# Applying a function for each value of an array

Tags: php

Considering an array of strings:

```
$array = ('hello', 'hello1', 'hello2');
```

I need to `preg_quote($value,'/');` each of the values.

I want to avoid using `foreach`. Array walk doesn't work because it passes the key too.

```
array_walk($array,'preg_quote','/'); //> Errors, third parameter given to preg_quote
```

Any alternative?

Comment: May I ask, why you don't want to use `foreach`?

Comment: Use `array_map();` http://php.net/array-map

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `array_map()` [<sup>[doc]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with an anonymous function (>= 5.3):

```
$array = array_map(function($value){
    return preg_quote($value, '/');
}, $array);
```

[**Working demo**](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ed942/1)

Comment: Ok at this point it's better a simple foreach imo. More clear. thanks tho will accept soon

Comment: @yes123 yes, I'd use foreach, too.

Comment: Why not `$array = array_map('preg_quote', $array, array('/'));`? Edit: never mind, the fact that this worked for me is a fluke of not having a `/` to escape. The second `array` is just being ignored.

Comment: If you use `array_map('preg_quote', $array)` and would like to pass third argument as `preg_quote()` delimiter, you have to have the same amount of 2nd and 3rd parameter on `array_map()`. Example: `array_map('preg_quote', ['/a', '/b', '/c'], ['/', '/', '/'])`. So, use the code in answer is the best in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_map()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php)

```
$newarray = array_map(function($a) {return preg_quote($a, '/');}, $input_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do (with PHP 5.3):

```
array_map(function($elem) { return preg_quote($elem, '/'); }, $array);
```

In PHP <5.2 there are no annoymous functions (first argument of array map) and in that case you should make a global function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach`. It's made for that reason. But if you insist:

```
array_walk($arr, create_function('&$val', '$val = preg_quote($val, "/");'));
```

Comment: @genesis Issues aside, how is this any more "complicated" (I'd use convoluted) than your own? The fact that it is on one line?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I'm not sure, it just smells more messy for me

Comment: The better solution is with callback. Unless you use older then 5.3 php.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative we forgot to mention is:

```
function user_preg_quote($key, $value) {
   return preg_quote($value, '/');
}

array_walk($array, 'user_preg_quote');
```

But still a simple foreach would be better maybe.